# Getting another page via ajax and showing data -> unable to display correct formatting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have an issue:

I have `Discussions.php` page that shows threaded discussions. I also have `generateDiscussion.php` page that creates a tree with discussions.

When I `embedd` the code from `generateDiscussion.php` into `Discussions.php`, it works fine. By `embed` I mean hardcoding same stuff like I have in `Discussions.php`. By works fine I mean that my discussions have proper formatting and `expand` and `group` icons work as expected.

When Iam getting `Discussions.php` via AJAX, and adding response from AJAX to `generateDiscussion.php`; it does not work as expected.

I also tried generating tree first in the `Discussions.php`, and then updating it over with new tree. As a result, first load (internal to page) works fine, but AJAX calls mess it up.

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
  <a href="#!/pageHistory">Please select a case first</a>
</ul>


                <script>
                function getResolutionBoard(caseId) {  
                    idcase=caseId;
                    jQuery(function($) {    
                        $.ajax( {           
                            url : "generateDiscussion.php?caseid="+caseId+"ts=" +new Date().getTime(),
                            type : "GET",
                            success : function(data) {
                                document.getElementById('browser').innerHTML = data;                               
                            }
                        });
                    });       
                }
                </script>
```

I incorporated this script: http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

See the screenshots
[image: bad]

[image: good]

Comment: Are you getting successful response(discussion.php) from ajax call?

Comment: Can you add your both the php scripts here

Comment: yes, and, as you can see on the picture, it does shows -- but does not have correct functionality. Firebug saying nothing.

Comment: Have you included the appropriate lib(which creates a tree structure and gives expand collapse functionality) on generateDiscussion.php?

Comment: Yes, as you can see, on the image, generateDiscussion.php shows everything properly

Comment: so you are saying its loading everything properly, but working partially ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you initialize the javascript on the ajax load ?

You need to call the plugin's initialization method (`$('#browser').treeview()`) in your success callback, *after* you have loaded the html code in the DOM.

```
 ... ajax({ ...
         success : function(data) {
             document.getElementById('browser').innerHTML = data;
             $('#browser').treeview(/*your options*/);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Could you please give better details? I tried using your code after the load, but it does not change anything.